# how to zip strings 2x3 in python

Tags: python, string, zip

```
arr = ["zx", "wu", "tr"] # new array should be [ 'zwt', 'xur']

for i in range(len(nums)):
            t = ''
            word = nums[i]
            for j in range(len(word)):
                t += nums[j][i]
            print(t)


zx
wu
tr
```

should create new array

```
zwt
xur
```

This code above works only if len of each str is 3 and total num of strings is 3 - ['abc', 'cde', 'ghi']

In case there is string of len 2 it's not working. HOw to transpose/zip it?

Answer (score 3):

Use the builtin `zip` function, which takes any number of iterables as an argument and returns a single iterable that gives you tuples of one item from each.

If you pass each element of `arr` to `zip` as an argument, you get:

```
>>> arr = ["zx", "wu", "tr"]
>>> list(zip(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]))
[('z', 'w', 't'), ('x', 'u', 'r')]
```

Of course, you don't want to have to enumerate each element of `arr` in your code -- that's what the `*` (spread) operator is for:

```
>>> list(zip(*arr))
[('z', 'w', 't'), ('x', 'u', 'r')]
```

Since `zip` gives you tuples, you then want to use `str.join` to turn those tuples into strings:

```
>>> [''.join(t) for t in zip(*arr)]
['zwt', 'xur']
```